# CoffeeScript not working on dropdown menus in Rails 4 application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, coffeescript

I'm building a Rails 4 fitness related application to learn the framework.  My focus is on improving the user experience, but I've run into a problem trying to incorporate a bit of CoffeeScript code into my application. The model in question is called StrengthExercise, and has a form with two drop-down menus.  Both menus are populated with contents from two other models/database tables:  Muscle Groups and Strength Training Lists.  The strength exercise model contains the following declarations:

```
belongs_to :muscle_group
belongs_to :strength_training_list
```

Here's relevant code from the form for a new strength exercise:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :muscle_group %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :muscle_group_id, MuscleGroup.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :strength_exercise %><br />
  <%= f.grouped_collection_select :strength_training_list_id, MuscleGroup.order(:name), :strength_training_lists, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
</div>
```

The two drop-down menus contain the desired data from my database tables. That's not the problem. Here's where I'm stuck:  When a user selects a muscle group from the first drop-down menu, I want that "event" to trigger the population of the second drop-down menu with relevant strength exercises. Data to accomplish this task is available in the respective tables, but it is not working.

I've done research on how to accomplish what I want, and found a couple of useful tutorials, including Ryan Bates' revised episode #88 on dynamic drop-down menus.  To achieve my objective, I elected to go with CoffeeScript simply because it's already built into Rails 4.  I followed Bates' tutorial, but for some reason, my CoffeeScript is not working.  Here's the script code from strength_exercises.js.coffee, which is located in my apps/javascript/ directory:

```
jQuery ->
  strength_training_lists = $('#strength_exercise_strength_training_list_id').html()
  console.log(strength_training_lists)
  $('#strength_exercise_muscle_group_id').change ->
  muscle_group = $('#strength_exercise_muscle_group_id :selected').text()
  options = $(strength_training_lists).filter("optgroup[label='#{Muscle group}']").html()
  console.log(options)
  if options
    $('#strength_exercise_strength_training_list_id').html(options)
  else
    $('#strength_exercise_strength_training_list_id').empty()
```

The script does not appear to fire on the change event. In the browser, when I select a muscle group in the first dropdown, nothing happens in the second drop down menu.  The second drop down menu SHOULD populate with relevant strength exercises, but it remains static (unchanged).  The data is available for this manipulation to take place, so I suspect that I've done something wrong in my implementation. Loading the page in a browser does not generate any errors.  I tried to use Firebug to troubleshoot the script.  However, I'm new to programming and can't figure out how to use the tool to troubleshoot the problem. The script contains console log actions, but I haven't been able to see or understand what's gone wrong.  I'm getting close to achieving the user experience I seek, but really need some help troubleshooting the CoffeeScript. I'd appreciate any help to achieve my desired functionality of the drop-down menus.  Thank you!

Comment: What are you embedding with #{Muscle group}? How are you getting the relevant info from the server? Also, your Coffeescript doesn't look anything like the JS in the RailsCast notes.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I'll review the turbo-links post. Muscle group is the table that contains names/ids of all major muscle groups in the body. I'm learning all of this ... not sure how to do this with an "AJAX call." Can you explain in more detail in relation to the code I have now.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the turbolinks comment. I missed the part about your console logging showing, so it isn't turbolinks. Explaining an AJAX call is too much to do here, but there are plenty of good articles on the web. I just don't see how you're filtering the second menu.

Comment: Nick - I solved the problem by writing the following:  .filter("optgroup[label='#{muscle_group}']").html()

Comment: Funny, I just posted the answer as you were commenting. Feel free to accept, or post the answer yourself and accept ;)

Comment: Amazing Nick!  As they say, "great minds" think alike. :)  I am going to mark your answer as accepted, because your question "What are you embedding with #{Muscle group}?" is what caused me to look very closely at that line of code.  I solved it based on your question.  You deserve credit for your response, because "your question" lead me to the answer that I discovered.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, @codeinspired, glad I could help (at least a little bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
("optgroup[label='#{Muscle group}']")
```

to this:

```
("optgroup[label='#{muscle_group}']")
```